# "Programmatically" add stuff to a class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, initialization, python-3.x

I'm writing a class that has a dict containing `int` to method mappings. However setting the values in this dict results in the dict being populated with unbound functions.

```
class A:
    def meth_a: ...
    def meth_b: ...
    ...
    map = {1: meth_a, 2: meth_b, ...}
    for int in ...:
        map[int] = meth_x
```

This doesn't work for a few reasons:

1. The methods aren't bound when the class is initialized because they're not in the class `dict`?
2. I can't bind the methods manually using `__get__` because the class name isn't bound to any namespace yet.

So:

1. How can I do this?
2. Do I have to drop out of the class and define the dict after the class has been initialized?
3. Is it really necessary to call `__get__` on the methods to bind them?

### Update0

The methods will be called like this:

```
def func(self, int):
    return self.map[int]()
```

Also regarding the numeric indices/list: Not all indices will be present. I'm not aware that one can do `list([1]=a, [2]=b, [1337]=leet)` in Python, is there an equivalent? Should I just allocate a arbitrary length list and set specific values? The only interest I have here is in minimizing the lookup time, would it really be that different to the `O(1)` hash that is `{}`? I've ignored this for now as premature optimization.

Comment: A dictionary with numeric indices? Did you forget about lists?

Comment: @Matt Ball: Please see the update, and impart relevant wisdom thanks.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: look at my updated answer. Are you doing this?

Comment: You don't need to do that. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly **why** you're doing what you're doing, but you certainly **can** do it right in the class definition; you don't need `__init__`.

```
class A:
    def meth_a(self): pass

    m = {1: meth_a}
    def foo(self, number):
        self.m[number](self)

a = A()
a.foo(1)
```

An "unbound" instance method simply needs you to pass it an instance of the class manually, and it works fine.

Also, *please* don't use `int` as the name of a variable, either, it's a builtin too.

A dictionary is **absolutely** the right type for this kind of thing.

Edit: This will also work for `staticmethod`s and `classmethod`s if you use new-style classes.

Comment: the problem with this is that m, is a class variable here and not a instance variable.

Comment: @Mo Zo: There doesn't seem to be a neat solution around this. This seems to be the price to work with the class methods during class declaration.

Comment: Why would it matter whether `m` was a class or instance variable? It can still pass `self` through to the instance methods...

Answer (score 2):

First of all Don't use variable "map" since  build in python function map will be fetched.

You need to have init method and initialize your dictionary in the init method using self. The dictionary right now is only part of the class, and not part of instances of the class. If you want instances of the class to have the dictionary as well you need to make an init method and initialize your dictionary there. So you need to do this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.mymap[int] = self.meth_x
```

or if you want the dictionary to be a class variable, then this:

```
def __init__(self):
    A.mymap[int] = self.meth_x
```

Comment: If the dictionary doesn't change depending on the instance, it's probably fine to leave it as a class variable.

Comment: This could be expensive binding all the methods (there are a lot), for every instance.

Comment: did you want the dictionary to be a class variable or an instance variable? cause in agf's answer the dictionary is a class variable

Answer (score 2):

It's not totally clear just what you're trying to do.  I suspect you want to write code something like

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def method_1(self, bar):
        print self.name, bar

    # ... something here

my_foo = Foo('baz')
my_foo.methods[1]('quux')
# prints "baz quux"
```

so, that `methods` attribute needs to return a bound instance method somehow, but without being called directly.  This is a good opportunity to use a `descriptor`.   We need to do something that will return a special object when accessed through an instance, and we need that special object to return a bound method when indexed.  Let's start from the inside and work our way out.

```
>>> import types
>>> class BindMapping(object):
...     def __init__(self, instance, mapping):
...         self.instance, self.mapping = instance, mapping
...     
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         func = self.mapping[key]
...         if isinstance(func, types.MethodType):
...             return types.MethodType(func.im_func, self.instance, func.im_class)
...         else:
...             return types.MethodType(func, self.instance, type(self))
...
```

We're just implementing the barest minimum of the mapping protocol, and deferring completely to an underlying collection.  here we make use of `types.MethodType` to get a real instance method when needed, including binding something that's already an instance method.  We'll see how that's useful in a minute.

We could implement a descriptor directly, but for the purposes here, `property` already does everything we need out of a descriptor, so we'll just define one that returns a properly constructed `BindMapping` instance.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def method_1(self):
...         print "1"
...     def method_2(self):
...         print "2"
...     
...     _mapping = [method_1, method_2]
...     
...     @property
...     def mapping(self):
...         return BindMapping(self, self._mapping)
...
```

Just for kicks, we also throw in some extra methods outside the class body.  Notice how the the methods added inside the class body are functions, just like functions added outside;  methods added outside the class body are actual instance methods (although unbound).

```
>>> def method_3(self):
...     print "3"
... 
>>> Foo._mapping.append(method_3)
>>> Foo._mapping.append(Foo.method_1)
>>> map(type, Foo._mapping)
[<type 'function'>, <type 'function'>, <type 'function'>, <type 'instancemethod'>]
```

And it works as advertised:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> for i in range(len(f._mapping)):
...     f.mapping[i]()
... 
1
2
3
1
>>>
```

Comment: This is _way_ overkill, he can just do `f.mapping[i](f)`.

Comment: agf: It may be overkill, but it solves the problem he was having, and also it was fun to figure out.  I think I prefer the accepted answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

This seems kind of convoluted to me. What is the ultimate goal?

If you really want do to this, you can take advantage of the fact that the methods are alreaday contained in a mapping (`__dict__`).

```
class A(object):

    def meth_1(self):
        print("method 1")

    def meth_2(self):
        print("method 2")

    def func(self, i):
        return getattr(self, "meth_{}".format(i))()


a = A()
a.func(2)
```

This pattern is found in some existing library modules.